# JavaFX thread makes the UI unresponsive , any alternative [Thread delay]

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

JavaFX thread is making the UI slow and it hangs.

This is the code, if anyone can suggest the reason or an alternative, it would be helpful.

It's an MVC application. when the code hits this thread it works fine and UI do not hang but it's not then it become blank and unresponsive.

It's a thread delay issue.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        setLabel(bidSide, viewResource_.getString(SELL), 95, 121, JFXConstants.jfxWhiteSmoke);
        setLabel(askSide, viewResource_.getString(BUY), 145, 121, JFXConstants.jfxWhiteSmoke);
        setLabel(bidAmount, df.format(0.0), 0, 122, JFXConstants.jfxGrey);
        setLabel(askAmount, df.format(0.0), 146, 122, JFXConstants.jfxGrey);

        bidAmount.setPrefWidth(110);
        bidAmount.setScaleX(0.87);
        bidAmount.setScaleY(0.87);
        bidAmount.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        askAmount.setPrefWidth(110);
        askAmount.setScaleX(0.87);
        askAmount.setScaleY(0.87);
        askAmount.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        unlock.setVisible(false);
        lock.setVisible(false);
        lock.setOpacity(0.7);
        root.setStyle(FX_BACKGROUND_COLOR  + fxBlackString);
        greyPanel = createRectangle(310.0, 135.0, JFXConstants.jfxGrey, 0.0, 5.0);
        greyPanel.setOpacity(0.6);
        root.getChildren().add(greyPanel);
        if (getFastFXController().getModel() != null && getFastFXController().getModel()
                .getCurrency_() != null &&
                !getFastFXController().getModel().getCurrency_().equals(LNFConstants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
            try {
                javafx.scene.image.Image image =
                        new javafx.scene.image.Image(setImagePath(getFastFXController().getModel()
                                .getCurrency_()));
                flagView = new ImageView(image);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                flagView = new ImageView();
            }
            flagView.setLayoutX(6.0);
            flagView.setLayoutY(11.0);
            flagView.setFitWidth(242);
            flagView.setFitHeight(108);
            root.getChildren().add(flagView);
        }

        bidRect = new javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle();
        offerRect = new javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle();
        nearTenorGroup.getChildren().addAll(nearTenorRect,
                createJFxLabel(nearLabel, NEAR, 1, 0, JFXConstants.jfxWhite, javafx.scene.text.Font.font(FONT_ARIAL, FontWeight.NORMAL, 12)),
                createJFxLabel(tenor_, FastFXView.this.getFastFXController().getModel().getTenor_(), 9, 7, JFXConstants.jfxWhite, javafx.scene.text.Font.font(FONT_ARIAL, FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, 14))
        );
        nearLabel.setOpacity(0.4);
        tenor_.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                popUpGroups.get(NEAR_TENOR).requestFocus();
                popUpGroups.get(NEAR_TENOR).setVisible(true);
                popUpGroups.get(NEAR_TENOR).setLayoutX(219);
                popUpGroups.get(NEAR_TENOR).setLayoutY(1);
                popUpGroups.get(NEAR_TENOR).requestFocus();
                tenor_.setTextFill(JFXConstants.jfxGrey);
            }

        });
        tenor_.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                tenor_.setOpacity(0.8);
            }
        });
        tenor_.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                tenor_.setOpacity(1);
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(nearTenorGroup);
        farTenorGroup.getChildren().addAll(farTenorRect,
                createJFxLabel(farLabel, FAR, 1, 0, JFXConstants.jfxWhite, javafx.scene.text.Font.font(FONT_ARIAL, FontWeight.NORMAL, 12)),
                createJFxLabel(tenorFar_, FastFXView.this.getFastFXController().getModel().getTenorFar_(), 9, 7, JFXConstants.jfxWhite, javafx.scene.text.Font.font(FONT_ARIAL, FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, 14))
        );

        farLabel.setOpacity(0.4);
        tenorFar_.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                popUpGroups.get(FAR_TENOR).requestFocus();
                popUpGroups.get(FAR_TENOR).setVisible(true);
                popUpGroups.get(FAR_TENOR).setLayoutX(219);
                popUpGroups.get(FAR_TENOR).setLayoutY(5);
                popUpGroups.get(FAR_TENOR).requestFocus();
                tenorFar_.setTextFill(JFXConstants.jfxGrey);
            }

        });
        tenorFar_.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                tenorFar_.setOpacity(0.8);
            }
        });
        tenorFar_.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                tenorFar_.setOpacity(1);
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(farTenorGroup);
        nearTenorGroup.setLayoutX(257);
        nearTenorGroup.setLayoutY(10);
        farTenorGroup.setLayoutX(257);
        farTenorGroup.setLayoutY(25);
        setItemsForPopup(NEAR_TENOR, getFastFXController().getModel().getTenors_());
        setItemsForPopup(FAR_TENOR, getFastFXController().getModel().getTenorsFar_());
        mapRectToPane(bidRect, liveBid);
        mapRectToPane(offerRect, liveAsk);
        bidRect.setFill(JFXConstants.jfxTransparent);
        offerRect.setFill(JFXConstants.jfxTransparent);
        root.getChildren().addAll(liveBid, liveAsk);
        root.getChildren().addAll(flip, toggle, lock, unlock);
        root.getChildren().addAll(offerRect, bidRect);
        root.getChildren().addAll(bidSide, bidAmount, askSide, askAmount);
        mouseEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even understand what the question is. Does the code you've posted run slowly? Or? You've put all the code inside a `Platform.runLater` block, therefore, anything inside will be executed on the JavaFX GUI Thread, therefore there is nothing about threading in this question.

Comment: How fast is the image loading? How big is the image you load? Where do you load it from (hard drive/jar/web network...)?

Comment: Platform.runLater() is used many times in the code (100+) to update the UI thus making the application slow but I can't find any alternative. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5966775/dvarga http://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian

Answer (score 1):

In two words:
Run something in another thread in backround: use `Task`. Something like

```
    Task loadDatesFromDB = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            List<Anfrage> list = ...something works slow...
            Platform.runLater(() -> {                   
                progressImage.setImage(null);
            }); 
            return null;
        }            
    };
    new Thread(loadDatesFromDB).start();
```

Remember, that you can "work" with main thread (where all your UI run) from another thread just from `Platform.runLater`

And you definetley must read it:
[Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: i did tried this but it gives an exception. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299892/javafx-task-gives-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-on-fx-application-thread

Comment: "Not on FX application thread" mean you try to do something with GUI (almost everithing in your Task) from another Thread. The answer: "Modifications ... should be done on the JavaFX ... Thread" is correct. Look closer into my sample: You do in Task something, what works slow (loading image etc.) and have nothing(!) to do with GUI. It keeps your main JavaFX thread responsible. And after that (after "slow" process would be done) you add "result" of it to GUI (set this image to label or whathever) inside(!) Platform.runLater (all inside it would be executed in main FX Thread).

Comment: I'm really sorry but I have no time at the moment to represent your problem by me and make some rafactor of your code in order to get it worked, but I use Tasks in some "slow" places in my JavaFX (in my case it's loading from DB in order to add it into TableVoew) - it works quite simple. And sorry for my English:)